# How can I simplify this AddClass/RemoveClass code?

Tags: jquery

I made this very simple code for button clicks.
Clicking one button changes it's css class to *active*, and removes the *active* class for all other buttons. This is how I made it:

```
jQuery(document).delegate("#today_button","click",function(){   
    jQuery("#today_button").addClass("active");
    jQuery("#tomorrow_button").removeClass("active");
    jQuery("#some_other_day_button").removeClass("active");
});

jQuery(document).delegate("#tomorrow_button","click",function(){  
    jQuery("#tomorrow_button").addClass("active");
    jQuery("#today_button").removeClass("active");
    jQuery("#some_other_day_button").removeClass("active");
});

jQuery(document).delegate("#some_other_day_button","click",function(){  
    jQuery("#some_other_day_button").addClass("active");
    jQuery("#today_button").removeClass("active");
    jQuery("#tomorrow_button").removeClass("active");
});
```

Is there a better way of doing it? If so, please let me know :)

Comment: What's your html structure? Are the buttons siblings? Can you you show a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your code for us to play with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a css class—`canBeActive`—to all three buttons, then do it all with **one click handler**

```
jQuery(document).delegate(".canBeActive", "click", function() {  
    jQuery(".canBeActive").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Are you using jQuery 1.7?  If so, consider switching from `delegate` to `on`

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".canBeActive", function() {  
    jQuery(".canBeActive").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that removes `active` on all of the elements, then set it back for the one you clicked. This really helps scalability, but there might be slightly less performance (negligible, really).

This approach might even allow you to use `this` to refer to the element that's clicked, meaning that you'd need only one function for all buttons you add now or later.